# How to dynamically add styles to Angular 2 component

Tags: css, angular

How could I add something like this:

```
<style>
    {{customStyles()}}
</style>
```

Style tag is being cut off from template. It's initially unknown, which style will be applied to which element.

In [Angular tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles) there is explained how to add styles to template, if template was defined as string in @Component decorator, but I found no information what to do if template is HTML file.

In [Angular Create Style Tag in View Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43988535/angular-create-style-tag-in-view-template/46079845#46079845) there is given a hack, not a framework tool, thus it does not answer the question.

Comment: There is absolutely no difference with the template being in another HTML file or as string . This part is not relevant to your question, IMO.

Comment: @Pac0 `style` tag is being cut off from template

Comment: Have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676203/set-style-dynamically-in-angular2

Comment: @Pac0 I need to make it with `style` tag, not styling particular tags

Comment: @Pac0 Thanks, that fits indeed

Comment: Your second link has a solution using Angular Sanitizer this year, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54348516/1657465

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass Angular restriction by using a [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer):

```
@Component({
  template: `<div [innerHTML]="styles"></div>`
})
export class OutputStyleTagComponent implements OnInit {
  public styles: SafeHtml;

  constructor(
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.styles = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`
      <style>
       .my-styles {
         ...
       }
      </style>
    `);
  }
}
```

This answer is an extract of [this other question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43988535/angular-create-style-tag-in-view-template?noredirect=1&lq=1), i've added it here because it took me some minutes to find it.